# react native - crash when initial project "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'reactDevTools.connectToDevTools')"

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm

I just created a React Native project and it crashes immediately when I type `react-native run-android`

The error code:

```
"undefined is not a function (evaluating 'reactDevTools.connectToDevTools')"
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "MoveObject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

If you know how to solve this issue, please let me know.

I tried to solve it by these ways but fail: 
1/ `npm install` 
2/ `npm install` after remove `node_modules`
3/ I also tried other versions of React Native: 0.57.7 and 0.57.4 but still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

> With npm,
>    you can run `npm install --save-dev react-devtools`, add
>   `"react-devtools": "react-devtools"` to the **scripts section** in your
>   **package.json**, and then run `npm run react-devtools` from your project directory using terminal
>   folder to open the DevTools.

try this

Comment: This did not work for me. I ran `react-devtools` but it is not connecting with the simulator.

Comment: Hi guys, it is magical, after 2 days and everything works as normal without changing anything. It hurt my head.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been resloved:

You need to add older version of devTools to the "resolutions" of your `package.json`, so it looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "YOUR_APP_NAME",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.57.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-devtools-core": "3.4.3"
  }
}
```

After that, run `yarn` or `npm install` and it will fix the problem.

Comment: I added the `resolutions` section you posted, then ran `npm` and `react-native run-ios` again. The problem is still there.

Comment: Did you remove node_modules first?

Comment: Yes. I got it working after using a slightly more extensive solution: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22863#issuecomment-451433222

Comment: Hi guys, it is magical, after 2 days and everything works as normal without changing anything. It hurt my head.

Answer (score 0):

run the below command, it will fix your issue(for Android only) ----

npm install --save-dev react-devtools-core@3.4.3

Comment: Hi guys, it is magical, after 2 days and everything works as normal without changing anything. It hurt my head.